# ng2-smart-table open popup on edit click

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I would like to open a popup page on the `ng2-smart-table` component when the user click on edit and new button, but I can't catch these events.
For instance I can't catch the `onEditRowSelect($event)` function, do you have any idea?
To make it short , I would like to remove the edit input field inside the table and open a popup page

```html
<ng2-smart-table 
  [settings]="settings" 
  [source]="data"                
  (editConfirm)="onEditRowSelect($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

Here is my `ng2-smart-table` settings

```js
this.settings = {

  columns: {
  },
  actions: {
    position: 'right',
    add: true,
    edit:true,
    editable:false,
    columnTitle: '',
  },
  add: {
    addButtonContent: 'NEW',                        
  },
  edit: {
    editButtonContent: 'EDIT',                        
    position: 'right',
  }      
}    

onEditRowSelect(event) {
  console.log(event.data.nombre);             
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to change the "mode option in setting in the ts file

```
settings = {mode: 'external'}
```

Now add html to this code

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data" (edit)="onEditRowSelect($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Now in ts file create that function onEditRowSelect(event) you'll find all the content there

```
onEditRowSelect(event) { console.log(event); }
```

If you want to open a modal then create a component first and then pass data into that modal. If you don't know how to create a modal then follow this link [material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: May I know which event I should use for add same like edit?

Answer (score 2):

I have a same issue. And I solved by add this code in this.settings.

```
edit: {
   confirmSave : true
}
```